# Count unique values from one column across multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

Is it possible to count unique values from one column across multiple dataframes with pandas?

**Example**

**columnname** in every **dataframe** which has to be searched for unique **values = 'userid'**

`df1: 1, 2, 3, 4
df2: 1, 2, 3
df3: 5, 6, 7
output = 7`

unique values in column **'userid'** across all **dataframes**
Thanks!

Comment: Those don't look like dataframes to me. How about some _real_ data?

Comment: Or, do all dataframes have a column userId?

Comment: @JohnGalt It's really easy to call me... just type @c, and then hit tab. c is not unicode ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ all dataframes have a column named userId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the `userId` column in all dataframes, then call `pd.concat` and `pd.Series.nunique`.

```
df1
   userId
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4

df2
   userId
0       1
1       2
2       3

df3 
   userId
0       5
1       6
2       7

series_list = [x['userId'] for x in [df1, df2, df3]]
count = pd.concat(series_list).nunique()

count
7
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy can be fast, use

```
In [255]: np.unique(np.hstack([d['userId'].values for d in [df1, df2, df3]])).size
Out[255]: 7
```

Timings

```
In [251]: [d.shape for d in [df1, df2, df3]]
Out[251]: [(4000, 1), (3000, 1), (3000, 1)]

In [253]: %timeit np.unique(np.hstack([d['userId'].values for d in [df1, df2, df3]])).size
10000 loops, best of 3: 184 µs per loop

In [254]: %timeit pd.concat([x['userId'] for x in [df1, df2, df3]]).nunique()
1000 loops, best of 3: 885 µs per loop
```